# preventing infinite loops prolog

Tags: recursion, prolog, infinite-loop

I got the following promblem: 
the following facts and predicates are defined:

```
father(avr, yit).
male(avr).
married(avr, sara).
father(yit, yaak).
married(rivka, yit).
father(yaak, yosef).
mother(rachel, yosef).
father(yaak, levi).
mother(leaa, levi).
mother(zilpa, gad).
father(yaak, dan).
mother(bilhaa, dan).
father(yosef, menashe).
father(yosef, ephraim).

are_married(X,Y) :- married(X,Y).
are_married(X,Y) :- married(Y,X).
```

I defined the following predicates:

```
married(X,Y) :- mother(X,Z) , father(Y,Z).
mother(X) :- are_married(X,Y) , father(Y,_).
```

now, the promblem is that mother is defined by marriage, and marriage is defined by being a mother - the result is an infinite loop, and the program crashes. 
 how can I prevent the infinite loop? is there a way to tell a predicate not to use a different predicate?

Comment: No, just use different name. This was recently asked and answered, just [browse here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/prolog) through some recent questions, and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/prolog/new) through answers.

Comment: possible duplicate of [left\_of exercise from The Art Of Prolog](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16325238/left-of-exercise-from-the-art-of-prolog)

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need to re-write mother ?

Just skip the

```
mother(X) :- are_married(X,Y) , father(Y,_).
```

Because you already have a (Data Definition) as mother.